# Error : Unsafe Encryption in prelaunch report

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

Your app contains unsafe cryptographic encryption patterns.

I have this issue in prelaunch report any solution?

[image]

Comment: There is not much we can help you with this problem. Just get your app APK file and open it in a decompiler like Jadx-gui and try to find the class `wra.e` which contains the problematic code. The strange part is that Google mentions that it is "dynamically loaded code". In the end this means that you use very strange libraries. I would try to identify which library is causing this error and check if you can avoid using the library.